# tcsh shell pass arguments with quotes and * to alias

Tags: alias, tcsh

1.I'm trying to alias my "find" command in tcsh shell at the end I want it to look like this:

```
find path file_name
```

instead of: `find path -name "*file name*"`

path is the path for find, and file name is **part** of the file name.

I tried this:

```
alias fn  'find \!:1 -name  "*\!:2*"  '
```

and it doesn't work. any idea why?

2. How can I print the command before/after it's execution? I want to see what's really running under the hood after I send an alias command - see what is the final command was executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You musn't be afraid to dream a little bigger, darling.

```
> alias fn 'echo find \!:1 -name \"\*\!:2\*\"; eval find \!:1 -name \"\*\!:2\*\"'
```